# iOS Push notifications dependent on site content

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, apple-push-notifications

Can someone point me in the right direction of how to go about using push notifications to alert an end-user of my app that new content on a website has been released?

The site that I am going to be using has updates that are put out frequently (they are also time-stamped with the date, so this may be easier to handle), and I'm trying to send users a notification once the updates are posted, whether their app is closed out or open.

This is my first time doing something like this, so I wasn't really sure where to start.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In order to have users get push notifications while their app is asleep, you would need a separate server/computer that observes updates from your site and then sends a push notification to everyone. This can be done in serval different ways. Take a look at [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/), they have cloud messaging (push notifications), database options (for your users and device IDs), cloud functions (observing and sending out push notifications). They have a free tier that may fit your needs.

Comment: I understand how to use the cloud messaging from Firebase, but I don't know how to use the database or cloud functions to achieve what I'm trying to achieve. Can you elaborate further or point me in the right direction?

Comment: In your app, you would need save each phone's Firebase messaging token and save it to your (Firestore) database somewhere. There are plenty of examples and guides on how to do that on Firebase's website.  Then you will need to figure out how get your cloud function to read the updates and send the notification. That will be the tricky part. I don't know how you get your site's updates (API?) so I can't really suggest anything.